# How to update a cell value in excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a spreadsheet which is having following columns:
TestID  TestData ExpectedOutput ActualOutput Result

I have separate python scripts for each test-id. I need to read the row corresponding to that particular test-id and after execution, need to update result in same spreadsheet. I am not able to update that result value. can someone please help?
I read the spreadsheet using Pandas.
e.g.
a row in spread sheet:

TestID      TestData              ExpectedOutput    ActualOutput        Result

Testid-1    Min_freq=5,Max_freq=60, Drive started    Drive started      Pass

My script would search for this testid and read the test data. after execution, it would compare the output with expected output and accordingly would update the value of cell Result. I am not getting how to update result value.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is a code that can be reproduced by others, including the error message/problems you encounter. At the moment, you don't ask a question, you have a vaguely defined task ("write some Python-Excel code for me").

Answer (score 2):

The only package that can modify/edit an existing excel is openpyxl
You can read it by xlrd, but cannot modify it by xlwt or xlsxwriter, which can create and flash new xls and xlsx.

However, if you are using another source to edit the existing excel, they are not editing the same ones but two template mirror files, be sure to save it before letting python to read it, and vise versa.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Pandas to read the spreadsheet but didn't find any function to write data back to same spreadsheet.

Comment: I read about openpyxl. It writes back using the call's indexes. but I don't have the cell's index values. I don't want that dependency in my logic. my code is searching the row using the key value. is there anyway to update the cell value without using cell's indexes?